# Why not just use DateTime.Now?

Tags: c#, interface

I have been trying to learn about interfaces recently.

I saw this piece of code and can't wrap my head around why you wouldn't just use `DateTime.Now` on its own. I'm unsure why the interface is useful, can someone explain please? The author of the book tried to explain but I don't really understand how to implement it the way they are saying:

> Has the programmer lost himself in a sea of abstraction? You might be
>   tempted to think so, but actually this is pretty smart. Imagine you
>   have to run some tests on a class that gives different results
>   dependent on the current time (or date). That’s not uncommon at all;
>   maybe it’s a financial application that needs to get the exchange rate
>   at a given date. So try testing that if the codebase has DateTime.Now
>   directly in the methods. With the INowResolver you can inject your now
>   and test for yesterday, now, and tomorrow

```
public interface INowResolver { DateTime GetNow(); } 

public class NowResolver : INowResolver { 
   public DateTime GetNow() {  
       return DateTime.Now;     
   } 
}
```

When I tested it the result was the same if I used the `NowResolver.GetNow` method or just used `DateTime.Now`.

Test:

```
        NowResolver now = new NowResolver();
        Console.WriteLine(now.GetNow());
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(now.GetNow());
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
```

Output:

```
07/02/2019 15:14:56
07/02/2019 15:14:56
07/02/2019 15:14:57
07/02/2019 15:14:57
```

Comment: Because you may want to *test* your code using different instances without waiting, eg for 10 hours.

Comment: ReactiveX for example allows specifiying a "TestScheduler" explicitly, to allow testing of operators like `Buffer` and `Throttle` that would be impossible to test if one had to juggle sleep times

Comment: Quite correct - I grabbed the wrong link. Can't find the one I was after now... Deleted

Comment: [Testing Rx](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html) shows how TestScheduler's Start, Stop, AdvanceTo, AdvanceBy are used to "move" the clock in order to test complex operations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for that link, it's really helpful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you are writing unit tests, it is important that the tests execute in exactly the same way, every time you run them.

If your test (or code being tested) uses `DateTime.Now` (or `DateTime.UtcNow`), then every time it runs you will get a different test result (assuming you are testing the property that contains said `DateTime`).

If you abstract away `DateTime` into an interface, you can make it so that when your test runs, it always returns the same time when `INowResolver.Now` is called.

Example:  *In this test, the time will always be 1st Jan 2018.*

```
public class MyTest
{
    public class TestNow : INowResolver
    {
       public DateTime Now {get;set;}
       public DateTime GetNow() => Now;
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
       var resolver = new TestNow { Now = new DateTime(2018,1,1) }

       var testClass = new TestClass(resolver);

    }
}
```

Actually, if all cases I've used this method, `Now` is a property, just like it is in `DateTime.Now`, not a function.

Comment: Thanks. I'm closer to understanding! Can you show a quick example of how I might use this to test for a particular date? That'd be really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The point here, as the book indicates, is tests.

Lets say you have logic that needs to do something special on Saturday. You want to write a test for this (quite naturally). Using `DateTime.Now` directly your test can only be run **on Saturday**. Using the interface you can have a mock that *always* returns a date that is on a Saturday, so the test can be run any time.

Answer (score 1):

To add upon the answers above, it can be used to freeze time:

> In a web request, you want to freeze time so that all your modified
> dates are aligned (i.e. not +/- by a few seconds

Meaning, you can implement an `IDisposable` Override so that time can be manipulated in a fixed scope like this.

```cs
using (var o = new OverrideDateTimeProvider(DateTimeProvider.Now))
{
    // logic
    entity.Created = o.UtcNow;
    // other logic that can takes several seconds
    var otherEntity = CreateAsync();
    otherEntity.Created = o.UtcNow;
   // persistance logic
   uow.Commit();
}
```

see [this repository](https://github.com/dennisroche/DateTimeProvider) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The `NowResolver` implementation will use `DateTime.Now`. Another implementation might have `GetNow` that returns last saturday, or yesterday, etc..

The interface guarantees that each version, each implementation, will provide a `GetNow` method. It is the class itself that determines what `GetNow` means to it.